# How to appropriately manage the memory for a singleton class?

Tags: ios, memory-management, background, singleton, nsobject

I have an `NSObject` subclass like this:

```
@interface MyManager : NSObject

+ (MyManager *)sharedInstance;

// More instance methods

@end

@implementation MyManager

+ (MyManager *)sharedInstance
{
   static dispatch_once_t _singletonPredicate;
   static MyManager *sharedObject = nil;

   dispatch_once(&_singletonPredicate, ^{
       sharedObject = [[self alloc] init];
   });

   return sharedObject;
}

// More instance methods implemetation

@end
```

I call it throughout the app this way:

```
[[MyManager sharedInstance] anInstanceMethod];
```

without linking it to any property anywhere. Is this correct or appropriate, or should it be recommended to keep a property to this kind of objects anywhere?

On the other hand, I have my app enabled for keeping updating locations in background mode, and I need this object to keep listening for events from the location manager while the app is running in background. How should I handle this object in such scenario?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The singleton keeps its own reference to itself in the `sharedObject` static variable.  This ensures that `sharedInstance` always returns the one and only instance

Answer (score 0):

Singleton exists once it is created, and never destoryed.